# How to build macro which will import modules from directory?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

Let's say I have following folder structure:

```
src
├── lib.rs
└── models
   ├── gate.rs
   ├── load_balancer.rs
   ├── mod.rs
   ├── processor.rs
   └── storage.rs
```

Inside `models/mod.rs` I want to import everything that sits in same directory, however, it is important to me that when a new file in directory `models` is created, I won't have to update or change in any way the `mod.rs` file.

In other words, I'd like to write such macro:

```rust
// mod.rs
import_everything_in_module!()
```

which would expand to this:

```rust
// mod.rs
mod gate;
mod load_balancer;
mod processor;
mod storage;
```

Is that possible? If not, why?

Comment: Do you mean `use gate` or `mod gate`?

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed oops, thanks! definitely `mod`, fixing it now

Comment: found about this on discord server: https://docs.rs/include_dir/0.6.0/include_dir/ . I'll try to implement it. I'll post answer once done, contributions are still welcome :).